# Preparing the Environment of MMDetection 3D on windows11

Tags: python, pytorch, jupyter, openmmlab

While preparing an environment with PyTorch and after installing all the packages needed using the miniconda terminal, an error showed up in the final step of the process which is the verifying of installation.

I created a conda environment and activated it,
then I installed PyTorch and all the packages needed using MIM.

- MMEngine
- MMCV
- MMDetection
- MMDetection3D

I also successfully downloaded config and checkpoint files using the following command ; 
`mim download mmdet3d --config pointpillars_hv_secfpn_8xb6-160e_kitti-3d-car --dest`

However in the final step to verify the installation I got the error message.

```
from mmdet3d.apis import init_model, inference_detector


config_file = 'pointpillars_hv_secfpn_8xb6-160e_kitti-3d-car.py'
checkpoint_file = 'hv_pointpillars_secfpn_6x8_160e_kitti-3d-car_20220331_134606-d42d15ed.pth'
model = init_model(config_file, checkpoint_file)
inference_detector(model, 'demo/data/kitti/000008.bin')
```

Output

```
C:\Users\ANIS\miniconda3\envs\openmmlab\lib\site-packages\mmdet3d\models\dense_heads\anchor3d_head.py:92: UserWarning: dir_offset and dir_limit_offset wi 11 be depressed and be incorporated into box coder in the future
warnings.warn(
Loads checkpoint by local backend from path: hv_pointpillars_secfpn_6x8_160e_kitti-3d-car_20220331_134606-d42d15ed.pth
```

The [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFYkb.png) is shown below and in the screenshot from jupyter notebook.
Traceback

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 5
      3 config_file = 'pointpillars_hv_secfpn_8xb6-160e_kitti-3d-car.py'
      4 checkpoint_file = 'hv_pointpillars_secfpn_6x8_160e_kitti-3d-car_20220331_134606-d42d15ed.pth'
----> 5 model = init_model(config_file, checkpoint_file)
      6 inference_detector(model, 'demo/data/kitti/000008.bin')

File ~\miniconda3/envs\openmmlab\lib\site-packages\mmdet3d\apis\inference.py:92, in init_model(config, checkpoint, device, cfg_options) 
     90 model.cfg = config  # save the config in the model for convenience
     91 if device != 'cpu':
---> 92     torch.cuda.set_device (device)
     93 else:
     94     warnings.warn('Don\'t suggest using CPU device. '
     95                   'Some functions are not supported for now.')

File ~\miniconda3/envs\openmmlab\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\____init__.py:350, in set_device(device)
    348 device = ___get_device_index(device)
    349 if device >= 0:
--> 350     torch._C._cuda_setDevice(device)

AttributeError: module 'torch._C' has no attribute '_cuda_setDevice'
```

Comment: I am also currently in the same stage as you. As far as I know, I believe this is because of the GPU. Currently, the MMDetection3D works only with CUDA which works with NVIDIA dedicated GPUs for fast parallel processing. Unlike MMDetection which can be run on CPU only mode, the 3D cannot (parallelizing makes sense since bigger data volume in 3D). Since I have an integrated Intel HD GPU, my machine does not have support for CUDA and hence cannot run MMDetection3D. Did you manage to find any other reason for the error/workaround?